# How would I insert a variable into MSSQL Database from php?

Tags: php, sql-server

```
  mssql_query("INSERT into User_Shoutbox(user,message) VALUES('$user','$message')",$dbhandle );
```

This code inserts the Variables User and Message into the database. But this code keeps giving me an error...

> message: Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'user'. (severity 15) in
>   Shoutbox.php on line 36

So how do I insert the variables into the Database properly?

Comment: Please do tell if need be any cleaer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not still stuck on this, but "user" is a protected keyword in SQLServer.

```
mssql_query("INSERT into [User_Shoutbox] ( [user], [message] ) 
VALUES( '$user', '$message' )", $dbhandle );
```

Answer (score 1):

$query="INSERT into User_Shoutbox (user,message) VALUES('$user','$message')";
mssql_query($query,$dbhandle );

Comment: This is result Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'. (severity 15) in

Comment: Which the collum does exists?